# How to fix my update query for my program in vb.net with MS access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

First here's my code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            'Variables

            Dim PatientNo As Integer = CInt(ID_TextBox.Text)
            Dim updatedDate As DateTime = DateTimePicker1.Value

            dbcon.Open()

            'If Selected "Cleared"

            If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                query = "UPDATE Swab SET isActive = 'FALSE', NextSwab = 'NULL' WHERE PatientNo = '" & PatientNo & "'"
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, dbcon)
                Dim dbada As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()


                'If Selected "Positive"

            ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                updatedDate = updatedDate.AddDays(7)
                query = "UPDATE Swab SET DateOfSpecimenCollection = '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "', NextSwab = '" & updatedDate & "' WHERE PatientNo = '" & PatientNo & "'"
                Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, dbcon)
                Dim dbada As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            End If

            dbcon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)

        End Try

    End Sub
```

***"Swab" Table***

```
|PatientNo|FirstName|isActive|DateOfSpecimenCollection| NextSwab |
     1       Aldrin    TRUE          15/07/20           22/07/20
     2       Joshua    FALSE         15/07/20             NULL
     3       James     TRUE          15/07/20           22/07/20
```

***My Program***

[image]
*Note that the AutoID is a primary key for PatientNo*

What I want to do is that when a Active Patient is `Cleared` it will update his status from the `Swab` database to `Swab.isActive = 'FALSE'` and his `Swab.NextSwab = 'NULL'`, however if a Active Patient is `Positive` then it will update his status from the `Swab` database to `Swab.DateOfSpecimenCollection = DateAndTimePicker1.Value`, `Swab.NextSwab = DateAndTimePicker1.Value + 7days`.

For example `Aldrin` exists in the record created June 30, 2020. If he  entered to the system with a Patient Status Positive then he will retain his `isActive = TRUE` in the system and his `DateOfSpecimenCollection = DateAndTimePicker1.Value` and `NextSwab = DateAndTimePicker1.Value + 7Days` will be updated. However if he was cleared then his `isActive` will be false and his `NextSwab` would display nothing or `NULL` .

(This is a test program, that's why the table above is short).

Comment: It looks like you have a `DataGridView` there so why are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery` at all? It seems as though you should be using a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` and binding that to the grid, then making changes to that `DataTable`, either via the grid in the UI or a `BindingSource` in code, and then saving those changes using the same data adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presume isActive is a Yes/No field. Don't put True or False between apostrophes. True and False are constants that represent -1 and 0. Could use 0 or -1 instead in SQL. Also don't put Null between apostrophes if you really want field to be null, otherwise will save word "Null". Use apostrophe delimiters only if field is a text type.

```
query = "UPDATE Swab SET isActive = FALSE, NextSwab = NULL WHERE PatientNo = '" & PatientNo & "'"
```

Comment: i erased the apostrophe's and the ```cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()``` and now its not giving me errors, however for some reason it doesn't update my table which is a problem, i don't know if my query is wrong but I just copied this query from the tutorials on the internet. thanks for the answer though really appreciated it :D